# Apps for blocking distracting sites on Edge

Tags: apps, microsoft-edge

I have a Microsoft Lumia 640 Windows 10. Can anyone suggest me an app for blocking websites so that I don't procrastinate. I have searched quite a few from Google in the Microsoft Store (which includes focus me, focal, freedom, cold turkey etc.) but none of them were there. So if you are using one then please also tell me.